# Como fazer require_once de varios locais em uma linha só?

Tags: php

Por exemplo, eu estou fazendo assim:

```
require_once 'Testeum.php';
require_once 'Testedois.php';
require_once 'Testetres.php';
```

Tem como fazer isso com um unico require_once? Com atributo eu posso colocar virgula:

```
private $testeum, $testedois, $testetres;
```

Tem como fazer com include, require, etc...?

Comment: depois de ler algumas documentações do PHP, acredito que não seja possível fazer exatamente o que tu quer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível ter um `require/include` no corpo da classe isso gera erro de sintaxe. Também não é possível adicionar um modificador de acesso (`public`, `protected` e `private`) fora de um classe. O único lugar onde é possível é dentro de métodos.

Comment: Oi rray, bom dia! Eu sei, o que queria saber, era, se assim, se tinha como eu, ao invés de ficar dando um monte de require_once, eu usar um só, e poder incluir um monte de caminhos em meu programa. OBS: Sem ser o __atoload

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o mais próximo que vc pode fazer é criar um arquivo de configuração (`config.php` ou `includes.php`) nele (na primeira versão) chame todos os arquivos que precisar nos demais arquivos só chame o `config.php/includes.php`. Se quiser pode incrementar ele passado os arquivos que deseja que seja incluidos.

Comment: Entendi, gostei da solução! Obrigado, rray!